# (Homework) Easiest way to format a table-like list and a logic issue?

Tags: c++, formatting, logic

So, my teacher gave us a document for an assignment due this Tuesday. Unfortunately its not very clear. I have a strong grasp of the basics of programming, but not with C++. Here are my questions.

**1.)** Right now I clear the screen with system("cls"), and I print the menu screen with spaces and \n for formatting. The doc says to look up something called stdlib.h and a clrscr() function and how it can be used for clearing lines i.e. clrscr(4).....

I found nothing on google, do you guys know what he's talking about?

**2.)** What is the easiest way to format a table-like list in C++? Example of what I am trying to achieve here:

[image]

The way it outputs each line is in 3 different cout's, first one with t: x and the 1st number, second one tacking on the 2nd number to the right, and third one tacking on the last number and endl. This will then loop until some parameter is met.

**3.)** Is my logic above sound? The problem is, I do not understand the assignment doc he provided, and my e-mails remain unanswered. So I've tried to just do it as intuitively as I can and thats what I came up with. Here is the snippet from the doc that I don't get:

[image]

I know its kind of an intricate issue I'm having so if you would like some more context for the last screenshot please let me know.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) Right now I clear the screen with system("cls"), and I print the menu screen with spaces and \n for formatting. The doc says to look up something called stdlib.h and a clrscr() function and how it can be used for clearing lines i.e. clrscr(4).....

try using cplusplus.com, it is awesome and will answer a lot of your questions.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/?kw=stdlib.h

> 2.) What is the easiest way to format a table-like list in C++?

Well personally, I think using the following function:

```
setw()
```

would be the best way to go about making a chart like that.
I feel this is better than just doing "\t" or "    ",
because it will do work more efficiently, and in a organized manner.
Let's put setw() and "\t" to the test:
Let's say we have values 8 and 10,000 and want to print the values.

```
cout << "\t" << "8";

cout << "\t" << "10000";
```

will output:

```
        8
        10000
```

while if you had:

```
cout << setw(8) << "8";

cout << setw(8) << "10000";
```

it would output:

```
        8
    10000
```

It's just an issue of keeping your code organized and looking nice.